# Adding a JS SDK in Greasemonkey script

Tags: greasemonkey

I have created an API using AWS APIGateway. Its a simple API using `GET` & `POST` methods. I will be using this API in one of our `GreaseMonkey` script to perform some changes on a specific web page.

AWS can generate SDK's for your choice of language. The JavaScript SDK is in zip file. Now, I want to use that `zip` file in my greasemonkey script. How can I do so?

I know that greasemonkey script provides `require` keyword which can be used to refer to a third-party library over network but all the examples that I was able to find were referring to `*.js` file. How can I use `require` to refer to a `.zip` file. Also, do i have to put that `zip` file on each clients machine?

Comment: You will need another external lib to unzip compressed data and eval contained scripts. You can load it as resource. Is it really necessary to handle a zip? Consider unpacking on a server and usage of unzipped files. Both `@require` and `@resource` will hold a copy on the client in the userscript's folder. Consider also compiling GM script into an xpi extension.

Comment: AWS gives you the option to download a `minified` version of the SDK, you should use that option instead of the `development` one. The minified option will give ou a `.js` file to download.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest Solution: Require the JS AWS-SDK over network. Add this to your script.

```
// @require https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/aws-sdk/2.52.0/aws-sdk.min.js
```